# Keyup Event is not triggering on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup, onkeyup

I had implemented code to detect Key combination of "window logo key" + "up arrow"  key event. I am showing alert message when user click inside text box and hold "Win + up arrow" . It was working fine manually. But i am trying to trigger same on page load, Its not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var e = jQuery.Event('keyup');
  e.metaKey = true;
  e.which = 38; //up arrow

  // Not working
  $("#test").trigger(e);

  // or

  // Not working
  $("#test").keyup();


  $("#test").keyup(function(e) {

    if (e.which == 38 && e.metaKey == true) {
      alert('win + Up arrow pressed');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text" />
```

Comment: Why are you calling keyup event explicitly like this `//Not working
    $("#test").trigger(e); 

    or 
    //Not working
     $("#test").keyup();`?

Comment: You need to move the event handler above the trigger. When you call `$("#test").keyup();` there is no event handler set.

Comment: Umm,I cant understand your problem, checkout this jsbin link  its working fine after i just removed two lines from your code
http://jsbin.com/bolaqimaxa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It worked for me when i moved event handler above trigger. Why minus point, is not my question valid?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way?
You should have declared you event handler before calling a trigger.

```
 $( "#test" ).on( "keyup", function (e){ 
     if(e.which == 38  && e.metaKey == true) 
     {
        alert('win + Up arrow pressed');
     }
 });
 $( "#test" ).trigger( "keyup" );
```

Comment: I  tried your code also , its working. But why window is not maximizing? Perhaps i did not mentioned in my question.sorry for that

Comment: Yes, you didn't mention it. I am not sure you can maximised the browser window fullscreen but you can resize it to screen.width and screen.height via javascript.
Similarly to:
function maximize() {
  window.moveTo(0, 0);
  window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
}

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have declared your event handler after the call to `keyup`.

So to make your code work, you have to write it ike this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#test").keyup(function (e){ 
        if(e.which == 38  && e.metaKey == true) {
            alert('win + Up arrow pressed');
        }
    });

    $("#test").keyup();

});
```

Comment: I tried your code, its working. But why window is not maximizing? Perhaps i did not mentioned in my question.sorry for that.

Comment: Nothing in your code is related to maximizing the window.

Comment: Generally Window logo key + up arrow will maximize the window.  I thought if i detect key combination ( window logo key + up arrow) , automatically window will maximize, If am wrong .please suggest me how can i do that.

Comment: This combination is "trapped" by the system so you cannot override it in javascript.